# Material is too dark in AR

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, light

I have a 3D model of a chair which I want to use for an Augmented Reality App. In Object Mode and AR Quick Look (Mac) the colours look fine. In render mode (cycles render) and when I place the object in my AR app (iOS), the colours of the material are too dark.

Can somebody help me and explain how I can fix this problem?

Thanks!

**Edit**: I have added light sources which brighten up the render image but don't effect the object brightness within my AR App.

[image: Render on the left, default scene on the right]

[image: Quick Look Preview on Mac]

[image: Screenshot from AR App (left is AR model, right is real chair]

Comment: You meant in Texture Mode not in Object Mode right? Did you light your scene up with environmental lighting or light sources? You should also mention that you are using cycles in Blender

Comment: Thanks, I have added the missing information to the question. 
The material brightness looks fine in object and texture mode. I have also added light sources, which brightened up the render view but did not change the brightness of the object in the AR application. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know anything about that AR App but if lighting helped solve the issue in cycles render completly then its maybe the same problem in that app, and you have to do something there

Answer (score 2):

If the albedo are reasonable, the problem is your light transport in your AR API. Specifically, it is literally too dark in the estimated scene. Unsurprisingly, given how janky AR is.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by adding a plain black image as the metallic texture when converting the .obj file to .usdz